# Should we allow reuse a image in a publication as long as it is properly cited and noted?

Tags: citation-style, graphics

Sometimes it is easier for the reader to understand a image if it is reused, even in the same publication. Just like we sometimes need to go back to a slide when doing a presentation.

What is the original reason for forbidding this? My guess is to save some pages. But now it is digital and manuscripts are already long and large.

Comment: If you have to reprint a figure in the same paper so that your writing is understandable, the problem is with your writing.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Do you mean reproducing the same figure in the same manuscript? If so, why do you refer to citation? And if you mean reuse in a different manuscript, there is no clear rule against.

Comment: It's pretty common for all images in published research to be at the end of the paper, with references pointing to them within the text.  Instead of putting it in the paper twice, just number your figures appropriately by chapter (e.g. fig 2.1) and reference them as needed.

Comment: I mean both. In general, I mean we should be more flexible about image use as long as it is properly cited or noted.

Answer (score 3):

> Sometimes it is easier for the reader to understand a image if it is reused

Not really. You can go back and forth when reading a text. I see no advantage reproducing an image within the same document.

> What is the original reason for forbidding this?

It is not strictly forbidden. I would call it common sense. The fact that you do not see images reproduced in the same document is because most people are convinced it is totally not necessary.

Comment: +1 PS to the OP: there are times when it might make sense to reuse a slide in a presentation rather  trying to page back and forth to it in real time.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you.

It would be great that simply by placing the mouse over the reference to an equation or graph, it would appear in the form of an overlay.

It is exasperating to have to go up and down in search of an equation and then recover the reading point. In more than one occasion I open the same document twice to avoid it, in one window I read, with the other I look for the references.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, which is about repeating images. I agree that repeating equations can sometimes be useful and appropriate. Mouse over won't work on printed documents ...

Comment: @EthanBolker, I read it as a proper answer for online or other electronic documents, which the OP does mention. And I agree that scrolling in such documents can be tedious.